# Replace all the strings value using FOR in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace, substr

i am trying to replace all the $first value with $second.

```
$first = "12345";
$second = "67890";
```

i've tried to do this, but doesn't work :

```
for($y=0; $y<11 ; $y++){
        $z=1;
        $firstsub = substr($first, $y, $z);
        $secondsub = substr($second, $y, $z);
        str_replace($firstsub, $secondsub, $first);
        z+1;
}
echo $first;
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? What is your expected output?

Comment: i want the output to be 67890 without echo the $second variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are bound to this approach, e.g. because of an assignment, but `preg_replace` is probably the way to go here:

```
$first = "12345";
$second = "67890";
$input = "12345 hello world";
$output = preg_replace("/" . $first . "/", $second, $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
12345 hello world
67890 hello world
```